# Access an Array with a Variable like $this::$var[]

Tags: php

I want to access a static array depending on a variable. My arrays look like `$blacksmith[]`, `$houses[]`, etc. I want to avoid creating a lot of getters and just do it with a function like:

```
function getNextResPrice($resource, $level){
    return $this::$resource[$level];    
}
```

Then if I want to access $blacksmith, the function will end up like:

```
getNextResPrice("blacksmith", 2)

return $this::$blacksmith[2];
```

Comment: So $res is supposed to be an array or object?  

"Because calling strtolower() on anything but a string won't give you the results you're looking for," said Obi-Wan. ;)

Or is the local $res not the same as $this::$res ? (Which seems confusing, to say the least).

Comment: That was to ensure the value of the variable was right (blacksmith instead of Blacksmith) but it's deleted to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to programatically resolve static class property and get a value from a given index. To do that, you can try something like this:

```
<?php

  class Something {

    static private $houses = [ 1, 2, 3 ];

    static private $blacksmith = [ 9, 8, 7 ];

    static public function getFrom($field, $id) {
      $class_vars = get_class_vars(__CLASS__);

      if (isset($class_vars[$field]) && isset($class_vars[$field][$id])) {
        return $class_vars[$field][$id];
      } else {
        throw new Exception(__CLASS__ . "::${field}[${id}] does not exist");
      }
    }

  }

  print Something::getFrom('houses', 1) . "\n";
  print Something::getFrom('blacksmith', 2) . "\n";

  try {
    print Something::getFrom('dnx', 3) . "\n";
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    print $e->getMessage() . "\n";
  }

  try {
    print Something::getFrom('blacksmith', 123) . "\n";
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    print $e->getMessage() . "\n";
  }
```

Here's expected output:

```
  2
  7
  Something::dnx[3] does not exist
  Something::blacksmith[123] does not exist
```

Comment: There it is. Thanks (Y)